# How to create a subclass instance from a superclass instance

Tags: python, design-patterns

I would like to create a subclass instance from a superclass instance in Python. Suppose I have something like this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, type):
        ...
        self.type = type # this will be something that corresponds to either B or C

class B(A):
    def do_something():
        # this method is subclass specific

class C(A):
    def do_something():
        # this method is again subclass specific
```

I have a function that receives an instance of A, and I need to create an instance of either B or C (or D ...) based on what A's attribute `type` is.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Is there a way out of this or does the solution need to be redesigned?

Thank you

Comment: You should research the Factory design pattern.

Comment: Can `self.type` actually be a reference to the desired subclass?

Comment: In my case it's something that corresponds to but isn't a reference to the subclass and I can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by redefining the classes A, B and C as follows. Note that you also need to pass the `type` value from subclass to superclass constructor via `super().__init__()`

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, type):
        ...
        self.type = type # this will be something that corresponds to either B or C

class B:

    def __init__(self, type):
        super().__init__(type)

    def do_something(self):
        print('do_something called for B')

class C:

    def __init__(self, type):
        super().__init__(type)

    def do_something(self):
       print('do_something called for C')
```

Then make another class which can make the decision whether to call B and C for you, and save that object locally

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, type):
        self.obj = None
        if type == 'B':
            self.obj = B(type)
        elif type == 'C':
            self.obj = C(type)
```

Then you can instantiate user class with different types and see that the correct `do_something` is called.

```
user_B = User('B')
user_B.obj.do_something()
#do_something called for B
user_C = User('C')
user_C.obj.do_something()
#do_something called for C
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear solution. I was hoping to avoid creating another class simply to instantiate the correct object based on the type but I might have to do as you suggest since I don't see any other solution.

Comment: Great. Please upvote/accept if the answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary that maps from types to classes.

```
class A():
    typemap = {}

    def __init__(self, typearg): # renamed this argument so it doesn't shadow standard type() function
        self.type = typearg
        self.typemap[typearg] = type(self)

    def create_child(self, *args):
        return typemap[self.type](*args)
```

When the constructor runs, `type(self)` gets the subclass of the object being created. This is then stored in the dictionary, so we can look it up using `self.type`.

The `create_child()` looks up the class in the dictionary, and calls it to create a new instance of that child class.

Comment: Your answer, however concise, seems too advance and concise for someone who might be just beginning to get a handle of python. I would suggest adding more explanation to the code.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for your response. But if you could clarify for me one thing, if I have an instance of ```A()``` and I pass in the ```typearg='B'```, the typemap will be```typemap={'B': type<instance>```, so when the ```create_child``` method will be called, wouldn't it return an instance of ```A``` instead of ```B```?

Comment: There's no built-in relationship between `typearg` and the actual class name, you create the relationship when you call the constructor. If you call `A('foo')` then when you call `create_child('foo')` you get an instance of `A`.

Comment: The question just said that the type argument *corresponds* to `A` or `B`, it doesn't have to be the actual name.